# MPMoviePlayerViewController hides the status bar so the navigation bar jumps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

"[Here](http://cl.ly/UygP)" is a demo.

As you can see from the video, when dismissing the view controller the navigation bar items move down the size of the status bar it seems. It looks like the status bar gets hidden when the view comes up. Anyone know how to fix this?

I'm presenting the `MovieplayerViewController` inside a `UIViewController`.

```
self.moviePlayerViewController = [[MoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsPath]];
[self.moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self presentViewController:self.moviePlayerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
[self.moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 2):

I force statusBar visible right after presenting in my iPhone app (tested on iOS 6 and 7)

```
[self presentViewController:playerVC animated:YES completion:nil];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
```

Alternatively, you can make custom viewController for playing video with MPmoviePlayerController

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem using the  [MoviePlayer](https://github.com/mobileplayer/mobileplayer-ios) library.
For me, the solution was simply to override the `viewWillAppear` method and force the status bar to be visibile, like the @VoidLess answer.

Swift 3:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}
```